# how run method for own object via this?

Tags: javascript

please help solve the problem. i make object Game:

```
Game = function(){ 
  var self = this;

  this.checkChecker = function(x_from, y_from){
    console.log(2323);
  };  

  this.start = function(){
    $('#moveForm').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(12121);
      checkChecker(1,2);
    });
  }
}
```

i initialized this object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    game1 = new Game();
    game1.start();
});
```

after click on #moveSubmit in console displays:
12121

but i need displays in console

> 12121  2323

why function this.checkChecker is not runned?

ps:
live example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVMmvw?editors=101

Comment: Inside the `submit` callback, there is no `checkChecker` function, that function is somewhere else, attached to `Game`.

Comment: the `this` in your function refers to the instance of `Game` while `this` inside of your anonymous function will refer to whatever object calls it, in that case the `window` object.

Comment: Backticks @raina77ow

Comment: Debug your code. Place a breakpoint on `checkChecker(1, 2)`. Examine the value of `checkChecker`. Step one line, and observe the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small Mistake.
Change checkChecker(1,2) to **self.checkChecker(1,2);**

```
  this.start = function(){
    $('#moveForm').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(12121);
      self.checkChecker(1,2);
    });
  }
```